# Mysql How to add Multiple Where Clauses to a single table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query on my table and it returns the table give below

```
SELECT sub.Subject_Name, count(sa.Attendance) AS Lectures_Attended FROM student_attendance sa
            INNER JOIN TeacherSubjects ts on (sa.TeacherSubject_ID = ts.TeacherSubject_ID)
            INNER JOIN Subjects sub on(ts.Subject_ID = sub.Subject_ID)
            where sa.Student_ID = 1 AND sub.Semester = '8th-Semester' AND sa.Attendance=1
            GROUP by sa.TeacherSubject_ID
UNION ALL

SELECT sub.Subject_Name, count(sa.Attendance) AS Total_Lectures FROM student_attendance sa
            INNER JOIN TeacherSubjects ts on (sa.TeacherSubject_ID = ts.TeacherSubject_ID)
            INNER JOIN Subjects sub on(ts.Subject_ID = sub.Subject_ID)
            where sa.Student_ID = 1 AND sub.Semester = '8th-Semester'
            GROUP by sa.TeacherSubject_ID

SubjectName LecturesAttended                                                     
    Php           2                                                             
    Php           3
```

Now i don't need that second row i.e Php | 3

I need the table to be shown like this

```
SubjectName  LecturesAttended  TotalLectures                              
   Php             2               3
```

Comment: It sounds like you're already familiar with the keyword you're looking for... `WHERE`.  Have you looked at any examples of how to use it?  Have you tried anything?  What did you try and what isn't working?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Yes i have tried alot see i want  the count of Lectures attended that is(2) and Total Lectures i.e (3) in a seperate column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reduce your query to:

```
SELECT 
    sub.Subject_Name, 
    COUNT(IF(sa.Attendance=1,1,NULL)) AS Lectures_Attended,
    COUNT(*) Total_Lectures
FROM student_attendance sa INNER JOIN TeacherSubjects ts ON (sa.TeacherSubject_ID = ts.TeacherSubject_ID)
INNER JOIN Subjects sub ON (ts.Subject_ID = sub.Subject_ID)
WHERE sa.Student_ID = 1 AND sub.Semester = '8th-Semester'
GROUP by sa.TeacherSubject_ID;
```

See [MySQL IF() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) on how the if function works in mysql.

Comment: Thnk u so much Allah Bless You

Comment: You are welcome @MansoorKhanAadeez, but I am not a muslim and don't believe in Allah.